# Could not called initState and update (riverpod state_notifier)

Tags: flutter, dart

## Problem

I'm using riverpod and state_notifier.
The initState() and update() that StateNotifier has are called and No. The other member functions can be called successfully. However, other member functions can be called successfully.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_todo_list/todo_list_notifier.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_todo_list/todo_list_state.dart';
void main() {
  print('start~~');
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends HookWidget {
  // ...
}

final todoListProvider = StateNotifierProvider((_) => TodoListNotifier());

class MyHomePage extends HookWidget {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  final todoListNotifier = useProvider(todoListProvider);
  final TodoListState _todoListState =
      useProvider(todoListProvider.state.select((value) => value));
//...
```

```dart
import 'package:riverpod_todo_list/todo.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_todo_list/todo_list_state.dart';
import 'package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class TodoListNotifier extends StateNotifier<TodoListState> with LocatorMixin {
  TodoListNotifier() : super(const TodoListState());

  Uuid _uuid = Uuid();

  // could not run.
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('init state~~~'); 
  }

  // could not run.
  @override
  void update(Locator watch) {
    super.update(watch);
    print('update');
  }

  // could run.
  void add(String title) {
    Todo todo = Todo(id: _uuid.v4(), title: title);
    List<Todo> todoList = []..addAll(state.todoList);
    todoList.add(todo);

    state = state.copyWith(todoList: todoList);
  }

  // could run.
  void toggleStatus(int index) {
    List<Todo> todoList = []..addAll(state.todoList);
    todoList[index] = state.todoList[index]
        .copyWith(completed: !state.todoList[index].completed);
    state = state.copyWith(todoList: todoList);

    print('changed toggle~~');
  }
}
```

restarted logs
not put initState() and update() logs.

```
Performing hot restart...                                               
Restarted application in 464ms.
flutter: start~~
```

Comment: Riverpod is brand new and won't have wide usage yet. You're better off asking on the package's github

Comment: Thank you.
I'll ask the question on Github.

Comment: StateNotifier is built into `Riverpod` and `LocatorMixin` isn't supported anymore
So you can initialize in the constructor or when you define your provider

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered on the Github.

> LocatorMixin is not supported by Riverpod.

https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/75#issuecomment-671255330

And it's proposed to note it in the document.

In my opinion, LocatorMixin is not needed to use with Riverpod because of [ProvidierReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/all/ProviderReference-class.html).

```
final userRepositoryProvider = Provider((ref) => UserRepository());

final userControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) {
  return UserController(
    // Read userRepositoryProvider and create a UserController from the result
    repository: ref.watch(userRepositoryProvider),
  );
});
```